# Problems in converting xml to json in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, xml

I have a xml file as a string. I want to convert that into a JSON. First of all I have tried to convert it doing this

```
 var string_xml = "<automaton><type>AFD</type><sigma>ab,01</sigma></automaton"
 var parser = new DOMParser();
 var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(string_xml,"text/xml");
 JSON.stringify(xmlToJson2(xmlDoc));
```

The problem is that when I do parseFromString instead of getting the string parsed like a xml I get this. What should I do?

[the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UF8M5.png)

The method I want to use to convert it to json is the next one.

```
function xmlToJson2(xml) {
   // Create the return object
   //var obj = {};
    var obj="{}"
   // console.log(xml.nodeType, xml.nodeName );
   if (xml.nodeType == 1) { // element
       // do attributes
       if (xml.attributes.length > 0) {
       obj["@attributes"] = {};
           for (var j = 0; j < xml.attributes.length; j++) {
               var attribute = xml.attributes.item(j);
               console.log(attribute);
               obj["@attributes"][attribute.nodeName] = attribute.nodeValue;
           }
       }
   } 
   else if (xml.nodeType == 3 || 
            xml.nodeType == 4) { // text and cdata section
       obj = xml.nodeValue
   }

   // do children
   if (xml.hasChildNodes()) {
       for(var i = 0; i < xml.childNodes.length; i++) {
           var item = xml.childNodes.item(i);
           var nodeName = item.nodeName;
           if (typeof(obj[nodeName]) == "undefined") {
               obj[nodeName] = xmlToJson2(item);
           } else {
               if (typeof(obj[nodeName].length) == "undefined") {
                   var old = obj[nodeName];
                   obj[nodeName] = [];
                   obj[nodeName].push(old);
               }
               if (typeof(obj[nodeName]) === 'object') {
                   obj[nodeName].push(xmlToJson2(item));
               }
           }
       }
   }
   return obj;
}
```

Comment: What is in string_xml?  Also, what does that parser error say?  In your image it's not expanded.

Comment: Why aren't you using one of the existing solutions like [fast-xml-parser](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/fast-xml-parser)?